# Angularjs ng-bind-html not wrapping text

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table cell that has some really long text. When I input the value, the text area displays properly, but when not in edit mode and just displaying the text runs off the screen and doesn't seem to be adhering to the width of the cell. I tried taking it out of a ng-bind-html as well and it still does it. Any idea how to correct it? I'm sure it is something stupid that I am missing.

This is the HTML for the cell when not in edit mode.

```
<td colspan="4" ng-hide="editableForm.$visible" ng-bind-html="details.releaseText"></td>
```

Comment: When you're in edit mode, you're presumably using a textarea. With a DOM element you should apply some CSS rules, ie: `width` to constrain the inner text.

Comment: I tried using width and different wrap options and nothing seems to be keeping in the right cell width. This is my latest attempt, I added it in the line: 

    style="width: 500px; white-space: pre-line; word-wrap: break-word;"

it still doesn't keep it in the right boundaries but it is a little closer. I even tried putting a text area in but making it disabled, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Could you post the entire HTML for the table, and all relevant CSS, as well as the text in `details.releaseText` so we can try and duplicate, or maybe share a Fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: thanks. I was able to find something to help....finally :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the following to your "td" style in the CSS.

`word-break: break-all;`

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply the following style properties....

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-word;
```

Once all of those were applied, it properly wrapped the text. Thanks for the help!